# Could hairline fractures be obscured by x-ray images

Tags: practice-of-medicine, broken-bones, radioactivity, radiology

I had fractured my ankle by the fracture of the fourth metatarsal was not seen in two X-rays that were taken. Only CT-scan revealed the cracks. Why is this the case? I was seen by an doctor who dismissed me after seeing nothing wrong with the x-rays. However, the pain persisted and I got the Ct scan only upon much hard work of visiting my GP and revisiting the radiology departments.

Comment: Diagnostic sensitivity isn't perfect. The CT probably has higher sensitivity, but may cost more or give more false positives as an initial test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to judge, as we don’t know whether your fracture resulted from an **acute direct trauma** or whether it is a so called “**stress fracture**” (due either to an abrupt increase in activity or to chronic overload).

While most of the acute fractures (in particular shaft fractures) are visible on lateral view Rx (+/- oblique or modified lateral views Rx), 
stress fractures are frequently not detected with
conventional Rx. It’s only about 10-14 days 
after the onset of symptoms (some studies even report from 2 weeks to 6 weeks after the onset of symptoms), that repeated Rx show a radiolucent resorption gap around the fracture that helps to confirm the diagnosis.

Finally, as suggested in the comment, in some cases, the sensitivity (= the capacity of a test to correctly identify the cases) of conventional radiography to detect metarsal fractures is not sufficient enough and further studies (CT or MRI) are needed when the clinical suspicion for a fracture is high.

*Sources:*

- Metatarsal fractures. Rammelt, Stefan et al. Injury, Volume 35, Issue 2, 77-86
- Hatch RL et al, Diagnosis and Management of Metatarsal Fractures, Am Fam Physician. 2007 Sep 15;76(6):817-826.
- Stress fractures in the lower extremity. The importance of increasing awareness amongst radiologists. Berger, FH, de Jonge, MC and Maas, M. European Journal of Radiology 62 (2007), 16-26.*